# How can I change computer name?

Tags: hostname

currently I have **" carlos@hoffman-c:~$ "**
I need to change the above to read **" hamburg@hoffman-c:~$ "**
I need to preserve all my settings data etc.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: do you want to change `username` or `computer-name`? do you want to change only what prints in your  `prompt`? why do you want to change it?

Comment: Actually, 'carlos' is your username, not your hostname. You can rename it, or create a new user 'hamburg'.

Answer (score 2):

Your **computer name** (hostname) is the name you see **after** the **@** sign.

Your **username** (userid) is the name you see **before** the **@** sign.

You ask for how to change your computer name.  But you indicate a different username for your prompt.

To make your prompt look the way you have indicated in your question.  First log out.  Then log into the console with this keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>.

You can't change your userID while you are logged in with it.  So you will have to logout.  Create 9r user a different userID to do this.

Log into the console and follow these step.  At the console prompt type this and press ENTER:

**Create a new user:**

```
$ sudo useradd tempuser
$ sudo adduser tempuser sudo
$ sudo passwd tempuser
$ exit
```

**Now log in as the "different user"**.  From that account run these commands.  Replace the "newUsername" and "oldUsername" with "carlos" and "hamburg".  In the commands below the **-l** changes the login ID.  the **-c** changes the way it looks on the login screen.

```
$ sudo usermod -l newUsername oldUsername
$ sudo usermod -c newUsername newUsername
$ exit
```

Now hit the keyboard shortcut: <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to go back to your normal login screen.

**Now login by the new changed name.** When you log in your prompt will look 
the way you have specified in your Question.

Once logged in your can use **System Settings** -> **User Accounts** to remove the **tempuser** id.

Comment: There is a typo on the **create new user** section: `sudo adduser **tempuesr** sudo`

Comment: @M.Becerra Thanks for the critique.  I'll fix it now.